# How to get Authorization Code after successful login -- Linkedin OAuth - Django, Python

Tags: python, django, oauth, access-token, linkedin-api

I have a Django website where users can fill in an profile form using Linkedin login. My logic was to have the user first sign-in using LinkedIn credentials & then retrieve/parse their profile & populate the fields. I was able to successfully make a user login using 'social-auth-app-django'. Now I believe my next step should be to generate an Access token. However, to generate this access token, I need the **authorization code**. This is where I need help. I referred to many resources, which all said, copy the authorization code manually & use it for generating access token. But I don't understand, how that's gonna work in my case, as it could be any random user accessing the form.. or am i completely in the wrong path??
Any leads or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For what purpose do you want an access token?

Comment: I wish to retrieve the logged in users profile info from Linkedin - like their title, company etc. My understanding is to get profile info, I need to pass the "access token" to LinkedIn application. Not sure if there is any other workaround for my requirement.